# 4 red balls, 3 black balls,2 white balls,1 yellow balls are available choose 4 balls out of it.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

4 red balls, 3 black balls,2 white balls,1 yellow balls are available choose 4 balls out of it.
I solved this question by a standard approach (that I will tell below),But I wanted an another approach for this question(It can be little bit but for ideas I would like to see it.)

My Approach:
Make Cases like Below:

Case(i): You selected 4 distinct balls -> Since we have only four type of balls Therefore No. of ways =1

Case(ii): You selected 2 same 2 different balls -> We cannot use yellow ball in 2 same case since No. of yellow balls is 1,
Therefore, No of ways to choose 2 same = $^{3}C_{1}$ And No. of ways selecting 2 distinct balls = $^{3}C_{1}$ in total 9 ways

Case(iii): You selected 2 same 2 same(in short 2 pairs of same balls) -> $^{3}C_{2}$=3

Case(iv): You selected 3 same 1 distinct -> $^{2}C_{1}$ and ${3}C_{1}$ = 6

case(v): Your selected 4 same -> $^{1}C_{1}$ = 1

$1+9+3+6+1 = 20$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What's the question?  I assume that you are selecting balls without replacement, is that correct?  What is it you want to know about such a selection?

Comment: yeah it is without replacement

Comment: And what is it you wanted to know about such a selection?

Comment: Are you just trying to count the unordered ways to make such choices?  In that case, note that $1+9+3+6+1=20$, not $10$ as you have written.

Comment: @lulu Presumably, balls of the same color are considered non-distinct, and the OP (i.e. original poster) is asking how many distinct ways there are of selecting $~4~$ balls without replacement.  **To the OP**: I agree with your analysis.  Further, to the best of my knowledge, there is no alternative shortcut (i.e. more elegant) approach.

Comment: @user2661923  Sure.  I was thrown by the final result being $10$, which is clearly too small.  But I suspect it's just a typo, the expanded sum is correct of course, just not the computation.

Comment: @lulu Sorry Corrected, it was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wanted *another* method, here is one:

Denoting the possible selections from each color by the indices of $x$ (with $x$ just being a sort of placeholder), if we multiply out

$\small{(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3)(x^0+x^1+x^2)(x^0+x^1)}$

the coefficients will *simultaneously* give how many ways there are to select various number of balls (because multiplying polynomials *adds* indices)

$\small{x^{10} + 4 x^9 + 9 x^8 + 15 x^7 + 20 x^6 + 22 x^5 + 20 x^4 + 15 x^3 + 9 x^2 + 4 x + 1}$

The resulting coefficients tell us, for example, that there is only $1$ way to select ten balls, $4$ ways to select $9$ balls...
and $20$ ways to select $4$ balls (which is what we are interested in.)

This approach is known as the *generating function* approach which you could look up if interested, eg get some idea [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Elohp/docs/math/2011-228/mit-ocw-generating-func.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! for it but I am yet going read generating functions after which I will revisit this solution.

Comment: You're welcome !